Command-tabbing back to Chrome moves to wrong screen?
I just setup a secondary monitor, and i have most of my chrome windows on my primary, and one window on the secondary.
Now say I'm on my primary monitor, working in a Chrome window. If I command-tab to another app, say Slack, and then command-tab back - it always moves back to the secondary screen, to the one window I have open there. No matter what I do.
I opened Safari and tested this - it doesn't occur. This is purely a Chrome thing as far as i can tell.
Any idea why?? I don't have any preferences set with Chrome preferring one display vs another. My dock is on my primary screen. I don't know what else to look into..
